# Replace variables with their corresponding values in source code chunk

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'd like to show parameter values and not `params$...` in R Markdown output. For example, the first code chunk below displays `params$file` in the output, but I'd like to replace that with `samples.txt`.  I tried adding a second chunk with `message`, but that outputs a white code chunk and I'd like a gray background like all other R code blocks.

````
---
output: html_document
params:
   file: samples.txt
---

```{r read, message=FALSE, collapse=TRUE, comment=""}
x <- read_tsv(params$file)
x
```
This just needs a gray background
```{r print, echo=2, collapse=TRUE, comment=""}
message('x <- read_tsv("', params$file, '")')
x
```
````

Comment: When I tried `message('hello world ', params$file, '!')` it is working fine.  Otherwise, your example is not reproducible

Comment: Try changing the echo options.  If echo=TRUE the chunk is gray and if I set echo=FALSE to hide params$file, the chunk is white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify the source [hook](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/). A solution tailored to your need follows immediately. For a **more general approach**, that replaces all elements in `params`, scroll down.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
params:
  file: samples.txt
---


```{r, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(stringr)
default_source_hook <- knit_hooks$get('source')

knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  x <- str_replace_all(x, pattern = 'params\\$file', paste0("'",params$file,"'"))
  default_source_hook(x, options)
})
```

```{r print, echo=T, comment="", eval = T}
print(params$file)
```
````

First we save the default hook that would be used depending on the output file type (`render_html` or `render_latex` etc.). Then we change the source hook: we replace all occurrences of `params$file` with its value and then throw the source code back into the default hook we saved before.

In this case this results in:

[image]

This magic works, because we only modify the source code that will be printed, not the one being evaluated!

---

**Update: A more general Approach**

I played a bit with your example and created a more general hook. It should replace all elements of the form `params$...` in your code chunks. It even checks for the type of value and adds quotes if it is a character value.

Check the following MRE:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
params:
  file: samples.csv
  age: 28
  awesome: true
  34: badname
  _x: badname
---


```{r, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(gsubfn)

default_source_hook <- knit_hooks$get('source')

knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  x <- gsubfn(x = x, pattern = "params\\$`?([\\w_]+)`?", function(y) {
    y <- get(y, params)
    ifelse(is.character(y), paste0("'", y, "'"), y)
  })
  default_source_hook(x, options)
})
```

```{r print, echo=T, comment="", eval = T}
file <- params$file
age  <- params$age
awsm <- params$awesome
# dont name your variables like that! works though...
badexmpls <- c(params$`34`, params$`_x`)
```
````

We make use of `gsubfn()`. This function allows us to use a function for the replacement attribute (not possible in common `gsub`). This function takes on the elements found, but, thanks to regex only the part after the `$`. So in this chunk, `y` equals `file`, `age` and `awesome`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the first example works for me, the second one with `gsubfn` opens X11 on my mac and then crashes Rstudio, but the output is right too.

Comment: Interesting. Im on a Mac too and none of that happened to me :D

Comment: In a new RStudio session, just typing library(gsubfn) loads the required proto package and that causes XQuartz to open (and if I keep that open its fine), so the proto package is causing problems.

Comment: Also, `is.character(v)` should be `is.character(y)` in the second block?

Comment: Yes! Missed that sorry :)